# How to reload page instead of continue script in Chrome debugger on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am using the debugger in Chrome 17.0, Mac OS X 10.6.8.

When I am stepping through JavaScript, sometimes I can add a fix and want to immediately abort and reload the page. When I'm not in the debugger, [F5 does not reload the page](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=73c83d887892a0a2&hl=en), but Command-R does. However, when I *am* in the debugger, Command-R performs a "Continue" (a la F8) instead of reloading the page.

Is there a way to reload the page instead of continuing in the debugger?

Comment: I believe this has already changed on the dev channel: in my brief testing, `⌘-r` reloads the page, even from inside the debugger. Can you take a look at the [latest Chrome Canary](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs) and let me know if the behavior is as you'd expect?

Comment: It does not appear to work for me. Command-R still continues instead of reloading.

I should be clear that I am trying to refresh the page while stopped at a breakpoint before the page is fully loaded. Chrome wants to finish the current page load (instead of aborting) before reloading.

Comment: It's not happening for me in Chrome dev and beta channel in Lion. I don't have stable channel installed.

Answer (score 0):

Developer tools doesn't have an option to do this. The work around is to add a "return" statement at the place where you want the execution to stop.

Varunkumar Nagarajan